# C# Typesafe dictionary where value depends on Key? IDictionary<Key<TValue>,TValue>?

Tags: c#, generics

I don't know the correct name for this data structure (Is it a Homogeneous map?), but basically I'm trying to get something like.

```
SmartDict dict = new SmartDict();
Key<string> NameKey = new Key<string>("nameID"); // Should this be a generated GUID for serialization that must be registered?
Key<int> HealthKey = new Key<int>("healthID"); //Should this be a generated GUID for serialization that must be registered?
dict[NameKey] = "Ryan";
dict[HealthKey] = 20;
String name = dict[NameKey]; //name is now Ryan
int health = dict[HealthKey];
```

Say this is defined on a Base class of some instance of a data class that isn't easily customized for each use.
By having a SmartDict attached to the base class, you can then add additional data to the class (and in the future serialize it as a blob) and have it data driven what types and additional data would need to be attached (as long as they too were serialize-able).

```
class BaseEntity {
    public SmartDict dict = new SmartDict();
    Key<string> NameKey = new Key<string>("name");

    public void Initialize(){
        dict[NameKey] = "Ryan";
    }
}

class HealthSystem {
    Key<int> Health = new Key<Health>();
    public void InitHealth(BaseEntity entity){
        entity.dict[Health] = 20;
    }

    public void DamageEntity(BaseEntity entity, int damage){
        entity.dict[Health] = entity.dict[Health] - damage];
    }
}
```

So getting the value from the SmartDict revolves around whether you have access to the key object or not. Useful for user authorizations, or making sure people don't mess with the data from contexts where they should be using a facade.

You could use a dictionary of objects, and just rely on remembering what type you put in, but I was trying to make something that would have less potential for mistake, and preferrably serializeable with WCF (But I'm assuming that's a different problem, that's going to required registering compatible types ahead of time etc, and using GUID's in order to match keys after deserializing).

I've been introduced to the ConditionalWeakTable, but that also has Weak references that might not always be wanted considering I want to be able to serialize this.

My first attempt without really understanding what was going wrong with my generics.

```
class HMap<K> where K : Key<?>
{
    ConditionalWeakTable<K, object> data = new ConditionalWeakTable<K, object>();

    public T this[Key<T> index]
    {
        get
        {
            T ret;
            var success = data.TryGetValue(index, out ret);
            if (!success) throw new KeyNotFoundException("Key not found: " + index);
            return ret;
        }
        set
        {
            data.Add(index, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "getting the key from the SmartDict" ? You're not getting the key from there you just create a new one.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Is there a class that I can use that allows you to generically get a value based on a reference key, that can vary by type based on the generic of the key? if not, how can I fix my attempt.

Comment: In order to use a key that is of a reference type, you need to have implemented the equals and hash function of that key type. SInce your Key is a wrapper, it would probably make use of the equals and hashfunction of the type it wraps. If you do this, I don't see a problem with what you're trying to do, but maybe you haven't stated clearly what your concrete problem right now is.

Comment: What value is the dictionary adding here? It seems like you want some "opaque" type (that you're currently defining as the key) which you can later extract the contained value from? It may be clearer if you can expand your example or give a second use case for it?

Comment: This question isn't altogether clear, it seems a normal dictionary would suffice, not sure what the "smart dictionary" would do differently.

Comment: Lasse, a normal dictionary is restricted to 1 key type, and 1 value type, for all keys and values.

This is largely an exercise in learning C# generics, but I've seen multiple uses for such a thing in Java, where the erasure of the generics makes this both easier and more difficult to implement.

It could form the base of an EntityComponent system, where it would hold components.

Comment: OK, so you want the *type* of the value to depend on the key as well? Because the *value* from a dictionary **does** depend on the key. As I said, it wasn't clear. You can't do that with the `[key]` syntax then because this property cannot be generic (by itself), you need to use methods instead.

Comment: Questions: Should `new Key<string>("test")` and `new Key<double>("test")` be able to be linked to *different* values? (My guess is yes). Do you only want *strings* as the "key" of `Key<T>` ?

Comment: "Should new Key<string>("test") and new Key<double>("test") be able to be linked to different values?" Maybe? Is it possible to do that and still be serializable? The reason key takes a string in the example is for some form of ID/differentiator between Keys of the same type after serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to achieve what you want with an indexer (as you can't have a generic indexer in .NET), but if you're willing to use generic methods to interact with your `SmartDict` instead, you can achieve a similar-looking API with minimal effort:

```
SmartDict dict = new SmartDict();
Key<string> nameKey = new Key<string>("name");
Key<int> idKey = new Key<int>("id");

dict.Set(nameKey, "Ryan");
dict.Set(idKey, 123);

string name = dict.Get(nameKey); // name is now "Ryan".
int id = dict.Get(idKey); // id is now 123.
```

`SmartDict` implementation:

```
internal interface IKey
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public sealed class Key<T> : IKey
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public Key(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public sealed class SmartDict
{
    private readonly Dictionary<IKey, object> Values = new Dictionary<IKey, object>();

    public T Get<T>(Key<T> key)
    {
        if (Values.TryGetValue(key, out object value)) {
            return (T)value;
        }

        throw new KeyNotFoundException($"'{key.Name}' not found.");
    }

    public void Set<T>(Key<T> key, T value)
    {
        Values[key] = value;
    }
}
```

This is not a very efficient data structure due to the fact that all values are ultimately stored as `object`, potentially leading to boxing - something you can work around later if performance becomes an issue.

Comment: The question isn't altogether clear if `new Key<string>("test")` and `new Key<double>("test")` should be able to store different values.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I now understand where your confusion was coming from. In my mind attempting to store 2 values of different type with the same key name/id would be an error, but that code is trivial to implement compared to the trouble I was having with the generics. Really the only reason the name exists on my example Is for the exception when a key can't be found (to aid debugging), in order to match what IDictionary would do (throw an exception). But if there isn't a way to have a generic indexer in C#, then matching the behavior of IDictionary is moot.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should not depend on the type of object but use a (big) enum to define your types in. Then you can use a Dictionary to store it.

```
public enum types{
    Name,
    Health
}
```

Then you can use:

```
Dictionary<types, string>
```

to manage your data

Comment: Messing around with 'runtime generics' in an attempt to store data is (when I encounter it) most times a sign of bad design/structure.

Comment: Half the reason of implementing it the way I was asking was to 1. Control Scope (public enums are global) 2. Have it typesafe, (you would need to convert to and from string with your answer)

Comment: Hmm, I see, I found a technique a while ago that may suit your problem. Try to do it component based. Send a message to an object that contains a list of 'possible respondents' and let then determine 1. if they want to respond and 2. what they respond. This way you can define those components without exposing them globally and you keep your structure clean. (this does indeed not handle the type save part of the problem)